# Is the Generalist badge broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Unless I'm mistaken, I meet the criteria for having [the Generalist badge](https://android.stackexchange.com/badges/14/generalist), and have for quite a while.  I would assume other users do as well, but no Generalist badges have been awarded.  Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is our current generalist query:

```
select * from
(
    select UserId as Id
    from 
    (
        select UserId from UserTagTotals
            where TotalAnswerScore >= 15
            and TagId in (
                select top 40 Id from Tags
                where [Count] > 200
                order by [Count] desc
                )
            and (select COUNT(*) from Tags where [Count] > 200) >= 40
    ) as X
    group by UserId
    having COUNT(UserId) >= 20
) as generalist
```

In particular we make sure:

1. Only tags that have more than 200 questions are considered
2. Your score is more than 15 on 20 of the top 40 tags

---

At the moment no one in the android site can get the generalist badge due to (1) ... over time as the site gains traction, the badge will pop up.